# unsure of the best way to go about using ng-options in my situation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm having some trouble deciding how best to go about this. I have an array of objects like so:

```
$scope.assessments = [
    {
      "name": "Goldman-Fristoe Test of Articulation - 2nd Edition",
      "description": "Description of Goldman-Fristoe test.",
      "selected": false,
      "templateURL": "Goldman-Fristoe-2ndGen.html",
      "subtests": [
        {
          "name": "subtest1",
          "description": "this is a description for subtest1"
        },
        {
          "name": "subtest2",
          "description": "this is a description for subtest1"
        },
        {
          "name": "subtest3",
          "description": "this is a description for subtest1"
        }]
      },
      {
        "name": "Oral and Written Language Scales-II (OWLS-II)",
        "description": "this is a description for the OWLS test",
        "selected": false,
        "templateURL": "OWLS-II.html",
        "subtests": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Peabody Picture Vocabulary Test - 4 (PPVT-4)",
        "description": "Description for Peabody Picture Vocabulary Test - 4",
        "selected": false,
        "templateURL": "PPVT-4.html",
        "subtests": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Comprehensive Assessment of Spoken Language (CASL)",
        "description": "Comprehensive Assessment of Spoken Language is a norm-referenced, standardized measure used to evaluate receptive (R) and expressive (E) language skills. Results on the individual tests are used to determine the Core Composite score, which provides an overall measure of the examinee’s language performance. Average standard scores are 85-115 with a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 15.",
        "selected": false,
        "templateURL": "CASL.html",
        "subtests": [
          {
            "name": "Comprehension of Basic Concepts",
            "description": "This 43-item subtest measures knowledge of words deemed necessary for children to succeed during the first few years of school. The student points to a picture that best represents the meaning of a word given by the examiner.",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          },
          {
            "name": "Synonyms",
            "description": "This 61-item subtest requires students to choose which one of four words has a meaning similar to that of the stimulus word given by the examiner. The student can respond either by stating the word or by nonverbally indicating a choice. Antonyms  This 55-item subtest requires students to express words that are opposite in meaning to those posed by the examiner. An open-ended format is used: The student must search, retrieve, and recall individual word answers.",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          },
          {
            "name": "Antonyms",
            "description": "This 55-item subtest requires students to express words that are opposite in meaning to those posed by the examiner. An open-ended format is used: The student must search, retrieve, and recall individual word answers.",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          },
          {
            "name": "Sentence Completion",
            "description": "This 61-item subtest requires students to provide words that appropriately complete sentences read by the examiner. Each item consists of a sentence with one missing word at the end of the sentence.",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          },
          {
            "name": "Idiomatic Language",
            "description": "This 49-item subtest consists of common idioms that students must complete. The student is instructed to \"tell what has been left out\" in a sentence that includes meaningful use of an idiom.",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          },
          {
            "name": "Syntax Construction",
            "description": "This 56-item subtest measures the oral expression of words, phrases, and sentences and the degree to which students use appropriate rules in formulating and expressing sentences. Young children are required to imitate and formulate simple phrases and sentences, whereas adolescents must develop more complex sentences. Each item is presented with a picture.",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          },
          {
            "name": "Paragraph Comprehension of Syntax",
            "description": "This subtest comprises eight paragraphs, with five to seven questions per paragraph, all of which are read by the examiner. Sentences in the paragraphs are of increasing syntactic complexity. The student responds to questions by pointing to one of four pictures that best illustrates the correct answer to the question.",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          },
          {
            "name": "Grammatic Morphemes",
            "description": "This 60-item subtest consists of analogies for which students must recognize semantic relationships between words to provide a correct answer. Pictures accompany the first items for young children.",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          },
          {
            "name": "Sentence Comprehension of Syntax",
            "description": " Each item in this 21-item test is composed of two pairs of sentences. The first sentence in each pair is the model sentence. The student must determine whether the second sentence has the same meaning as the model sentence. Sentences differ only in terms of syntactic structure (word order, clause construction, and so forth).",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          },
          {
            "name": "Grammaticality Judgment ",
            "description": "This 57-item subtest requires students to indicate whether grammatically correct and noncorrect sentences presented by the examiner are \"the correct way to speak in class.\" If the student indicates that a sentence is not grammatically correct, he or she must fix it by changing only one word and not the meaning of the sentence. ",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          },
          {
            "name": "Nonliteral Language Test",
            "description": "This 50-item subtest comprises sentences read by the examiner that include figurative, indirect, or sarcastic language by the speaker. After reading the sentence(s), the student is required to explain what was meant by the nonliteral language.",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          },
          {
            "name": "Meaning from Context",
            "description": "This 48-item subtest includes sentences that contain one unknown or difficult word. After the examiner reads the sentence, the student must articulate what he or she thinks the target word means given the context of the sentence.",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          },
          {
            "name": "Inference Test",
            "description": "This 52-item subtest includes episodes of two to three sentences read by the examiner that require utilization of background knowledge to comprehend. A question accompanies each episode; the student answers each question in her or his own words, based on an understanding of the sentences.",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          },
          {
            "name": "Ambiguous Sentences Test",
            "description": "In this 43-item subtest, the examiner reads a sentence that has two potential meanings. The student is required to explain the two possible meanings of the sentence.",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          },
          {
            "name": "Pragmatic Judgment",
            "description": " This 60-item test is made up of a series of stories describing everyday life situations. After listening to these vignettes, the students must either judge the appropriateness of the language used by those in the story or suggest language appropriate for the given situation. ",
            "standardScore": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "percentile": 0,
            "descriptionOptions": [{"name": "Below Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Average", "selected": false}, {"name": "Above Average", "selected": false},]
          }]
        },
        {
          "name": "Pragmatic Language Skills Inventory (PLSI)",
          "description": "PLSI description",
          "selected": false,
          "templateURL": "PLSI.html",
          "subtests": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Structured Photographic Expressive Language Text - 3 (SPELT-3)",
          "description": "SPELT-3 description",
          "selected": false,
          "templateURL": "SPELT-3.html",
          "subtests": []
        }
      ];
```

I am currently working on the `Comprehensive Assessment of Spoken Language (CASL)` assessment object. And I'm trying to come up with a table I can dynamically add `subtests` to. Using ng-include I load the `templateURL`. This is the one for the `CASL` object:

```
<h4><b><u>{{assessment.name}}</u>:</b></h4>
<p>{{assessment.description}}</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Subtests</th>
    <th>Standard Score</th>
    <th>Percentile</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="i in CASLgetDesiredSubtestCount()">
    <td>
      <!-- <select ng-model="CASLselectedSubtest" ng-blur="CASLaddSubtest(CASLselectedSubtest)" ng-change="CASLselectedSubtestDescriptionOptionsOnChange(CASLselectedSubtest)" ng-options="subtest as subtest.name for subtest in assessment.subtests | orderBy:'name' | filter:subtest.selected=false"></select> -->
      <select ng-model="CASLselectedSubtest" ng-change="CASLaddSubtest(CASLselectedSubtest)" ng-options="subtest as subtest.name for subtest in assessment.subtests | orderBy:'name' | filter:subtest.selected=false">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="CASLsubtestStandardScore" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="CASLsubtestPercentile" /></td>
    <td>
      <select ng-model="CASLselectedSubtestDescription" ng-change="" ng-options="descriptionOption as descriptionOptions.name for descriptionOptions in assessment.subtests[CASLselectedSubtestIndex].descriptionOptions">
        <!-- <option ng-repeat="description in CASLselectedSubtestDescriptionOptions" value="description">{{description}}</option> -->
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button ng-click="CASLaddDesiredSubTest()">Add Subtest</button>
<br />
<div ng-repeat="subtest in CASLsubtests">
  <div ng-show="subtest.selected">
    <p><b><u>{{subtest.name}}</u>:</b></p>
    <p>{{subtest.description}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
```

I'm pretty new to `AngularJS`, so I'm not sure the best way to go about doing this. Of course later on I will need to save the `selected subtests` into a database.

My goal is to be able to click the `Add Subtest Button`, which adds another table row, and bind those values to a JSON object that I can potentially send off to a database. I'm confused on how to go about this exactly. Do I need to have dynamically added `ng-models`? If so, how do I do that? Or, is there a way to get the currently selected row object and be able to use the `this` keyword on it maybe? What I have is almost working but not exactly how I was hoping for it to work, I'm confused on how to best approach this...

I hope this post makes sense, I currently don't have a lot of time to spend formatting my question. Hopefully it is good enough to get my point across. If you need more code posted, I can go ahead and just post all of it if need be. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I'm going to try to help you, but I need a little more information...What is supposed to appear on the NEW row?  If you were adding it manually, what would it be? Is it the subtest.name and subtest.description?

Comment: If you look at the HTML section, it's a select list of all the subtests, text input for standard score and one for percentile, and another select for the description options.

Comment: Please forgive me.  I don't see text input for standard score and percentile.  I do see column "headings" for these, but I do not see where you are calling the detail values.

Comment: I don't have it bound yet. But they are the 2 text inputs there in the table

Comment: @RaniRadcliff I added the `ng-model` bindings to the text fields so if your still looking to help, it should make them easier to see. Sorry I was on mobile when I last replied.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly...your `ng-repeat="subtest in CASLsubtests"` should update with updates to your `CASLsubtests` object.

Therefore if your `CASLaddDesiredSubTest()` function modifies the `CASLsubtests` object, then you should see the newly added subtests appear in your list.

`CASLsubtests` acts as your model, so when you need to do anything further with the data, you can access it easily.